# Installation failure with error code 2068119551

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016, installation

I have been making attempts at installing MS SQL Server 2016 SP2 on my Windows 10 physical machine. Installation keeps failing with the following exit code: 2068119551, saying that it "attempted to perform an unauthorized operation".

I tried it using the firewall, windows defender turned off. Still no luck.

Please see details from the log below-

> ```
> (01) 2019-11-25 19:32:16 Slp: ----------------------------------------------------------------------
> (01) 2019-11-25 19:32:16 Slp: Skipping Action: DeleteUninstalledPatchRegistryAndCacheFolderAction
> (01) 2019-11-25 19:32:16 Slp: Action is being skipped due to the following restrictions: 
> (01) 2019-11-25 19:32:16 Slp: Condition "Do any of the specified features match the expected scenario Uninstall" did not pass as it returned false and true was expected.
> (01) 2019-11-25 19:32:16 Slp: Completed Action: ExecuteExtendedTimingsWorkflow, returned True
> (01) 2019-11-25 19:32:16 Slp: ----------------------------------------------------------------------
> (01) 2019-11-25 19:32:16 Slp: Running Action: DeleteUpdates
> (01) 2019-11-25 19:32:16 Slp: Deleting folder 'C:\Users\adida\AppData\Local\Temp\SQL Server 2016'.
> (01) 2019-11-25 19:32:16 Slp: Sco: Directory C:\Users\adida\AppData\Local\Temp\SQL Server 2016 does not exist
> (01) 2019-11-25 19:32:16 Slp: Completed Action: DeleteUpdates, returned True
> (01) 2019-11-25 19:32:16 Slp: ----------------------------------------------------------------------
> (01) 2019-11-25 19:32:16 Slp: Running Action: ExecuteCloseWorkflow
> (01) 2019-11-25 19:32:16 Slp: Workflow to execute: 'CLOSE'
> (01) 2019-11-25 19:32:16 Slp: ----------------------------------------------------------------------
> (01) 2019-11-25 19:32:16 Slp: Running Action: DetermineProductFeatureSummary
> (01) 2019-11-25 19:32:16 Slp: Completed Action: DetermineProductFeatureSummary, returned True
> (01) 2019-11-25 19:32:16 Slp: ----------------------------------------------------------------------
> (01) 2019-11-25 19:32:16 Slp: Running Action: ProduceStatusLogs
> (01) 2019-11-25 19:32:17 Slp: Completed Action: ProduceStatusLogs, returned True
> (01) 2019-11-25 19:32:17 Slp: ----------------------------------------------------------------------
> (01) 2019-11-25 19:32:17 Slp: Running Action: FinalizeProgressStatus
> (01) 2019-11-25 19:32:17 Slp: Completed Action: FinalizeProgressStatus, returned True
> (01) 2019-11-25 19:32:17 Slp: ----------------------------------------------------------------------
> (01) 2019-11-25 19:32:17 Slp: Running Action: RebootMessageAction
> (01) 2019-11-25 19:32:17 Slp: Completed Action: RebootMessageAction, returned True
> (01) 2019-11-25 19:32:17 Slp: ----------------------------------------------------------------------
> (01) 2019-11-25 19:32:17 Slp: Skipping Action: FinishPage
> (01) 2019-11-25 19:32:17 Slp: Action is being skipped due to the following restrictions: 
> (01) 2019-11-25 19:32:17 Slp: Condition "Is the user's scenario set to EditionUpgrade" did not pass as it returned false and true was expected.
> (01) 2019-11-25 19:32:17 Slp: ----------------------------------------------------------------------
> (01) 2019-11-25 19:32:17 Slp: Running Action: CloseUI
> (01) 2019-11-25 19:32:17 Slp: Stop action skipped in UI Mode Quiet
> (01) 2019-11-25 19:32:17 Slp: Completed Action: CloseUI, returned True
> (01) 2019-11-25 19:32:17 Slp: Completed Action: ExecuteCloseWorkflow, returned True
> (01) 2019-11-25 19:32:17 Slp: Completed Action: ExecuteCompleteWorkflow, returned True
> (01) 2019-11-25 19:32:17 Slp: SetupTelemetry: Writing Telemetry to Datastore
> (01) 2019-11-25 19:32:19 Slp: 
> (01) 2019-11-25 19:32:19 Slp: 
> (01) 2019-11-25 19:32:19 Slp: ----------------------------------------------------------------------
> (01) 2019-11-25 19:32:19 Slp: 
> (01) 2019-11-25 19:32:19 Slp: Error result: -2068119551
> (01) 2019-11-25 19:32:19 Slp: Result facility code: 1211
> (01) 2019-11-25 19:32:19 Slp: Result error code: 1
> (01) 2019-11-25 19:32:19 Slp: WER: Application level consent value 'True' was mapped to consent status 'WerConsentApproved'
> (01) 2019-11-25 19:32:20 Slp: WER: Result of the submission:: 'WerReportQueued'
> (01) 2019-11-25 19:32:20 Slp: WER: Submitted 1 of 1 failures to the Watson data repository
> (01) 2019-11-25 19:32:20 Slp: SetupTelemetry: Closing Telemetry Session
> (01) 2019-11-25 19:32:20 Slp: Sco: Attempting to create base registry key HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, machine 
> (01) 2019-11-25 19:32:20 Slp: Sco: Attempting to open registry subkey SOFTWARE\Microsoft\SQMClient
> (01) 2019-11-25 19:32:20 Slp: Sco: Attempting to get registry value MachineId
> (01) 2019-11-25 19:32:20 Slp: Sco: Attempting to create base registry key HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, machine 
> (01) 2019-11-25 19:32:20 Slp: Sco: Attempting to open registry subkey Software\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server\130
> (01) 2019-11-25 19:32:20 Slp: Sco: Attempting to get registry value CustomerFeedback
> (01) 2019-11-25 19:32:20 Slp: Sco: Attempting to get registry value EnableErrorReporting
> (01) 2019-11-25 19:32:20 Slp: Sco: Attempting to create base registry key HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, machine 
> (01) 2019-11-25 19:32:20 Slp: Sco: Attempting to open registry subkey Software\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server\Instance Names
> (01) 2019-11-25 19:32:20 Slp: Sco: Attempting to open registry subkey SQL
> (01) 2019-11-25 19:32:20 Slp: Sco: Attempting to get registry value SQLEXPRESS
> (01) 2019-11-25 19:32:20 Slp: Sco: Attempting to create base registry key HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, machine 
> (01) 2019-11-25 19:32:20 Slp: Sco: Attempting to open registry subkey Software\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL13.SQLEXPRESS\CPE
> (01) 2019-11-25 19:32:20 Slp: Sco: Attempting to get registry value CustomerFeedback
> (01) 2019-11-25 19:32:20 Slp: Sco: Attempting to get registry value EnableErrorReporting
> (01) 2019-11-25 19:32:20 Slp: Sco: Attempting to create base registry key HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, machine 
> (01) 2019-11-25 19:32:20 Slp: Sco: Attempting to open registry subkey Software\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server\Instance Names
> (01) 2019-11-25 19:32:20 Slp: Sco: Attempting to open registry subkey OLAP
> (01) 2019-11-25 19:32:20 Slp: Sco: Attempting to create base registry key HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, machine 
> (01) 2019-11-25 19:32:20 Slp: Sco: Attempting to open registry subkey Software\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server\Instance Names
> (01) 2019-11-25 19:32:20 Slp: Sco: Attempting to open registry subkey RS
> (01) 2019-11-25 19:32:20 Slp: SetupTelemetry: Telemetry has an active session with 88 events.
> ```

Summary report from the last failed attempt:

> ```
> Overall summary:
>   Final result:                  Failed: see details below
>   Exit code (Decimal):           -2068119551
>   Start time:                    2019-11-26 19:57:56
>   End time:                      2019-11-26 20:04:01
>   Requested action:              Install
> Setup completed with required actions for features.
> Troubleshooting information for those features:
>   Next step for SQLEngine:       Use the following information to resolve the error, uninstall this feature, and then run the setup process again.
> Machine Properties:
>   Machine name:                  DESKTOP-V440KD1
>   Machine processor count:       4
>   OS version:                    Microsoft Windows 10 Pro (10.0.18362)
>   OS service pack:               
>   OS region:                     Canada
>   OS language:                   English (United States)
>   OS architecture:               x64
>   Process architecture:          64 Bit
>   OS clustered:                  No
> Product features discovered:
> Product              Instance             Instance ID                    Feature                                  Language             Edition              Version         Clustered  Configured
> Package properties:
>   Description:                   Microsoft SQL Server 2016 
>   ProductName:                   SQL Server 2016
>   Type:                          RTM
>   Version:                       13
>   Installation location:         C:\SQLServer2016Media\Express_ENU\x64\setup\
>   Installation edition:          Express
>   Slipstream:                    True
>   SP Level                       2
> Product Update Status:
>   User selected not to include product updates.
> User Input Settings:
>   ACTION:                        Install
>   ADDCURRENTUSERASSQLADMIN:      true
>   AGTSVCACCOUNT:                 NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE
>   AGTSVCPASSWORD:                *****
>   AGTSVCSTARTUPTYPE:             Disabled
>   ASBACKUPDIR:                   Backup
>   ASCOLLATION:                   Latin1_General_CI_AS
>   ASCONFIGDIR:                   Config
>   ASDATADIR:                     Data
>   ASLOGDIR:                      Log
>   ASPROVIDERMSOLAP:              1
>   ASSERVERMODE:                  MULTIDIMENSIONAL
>   ASSVCACCOUNT:                  <empty>
>   ASSVCPASSWORD:                 <empty>
>   ASSVCSTARTUPTYPE:              Automatic
>   ASSYSADMINACCOUNTS:            <empty>
>   ASTELSVCACCT:                  <empty>
>   ASTELSVCPASSWORD:              <empty>
>   ASTELSVCSTARTUPTYPE:           0
>   ASTEMPDIR:                     Temp
>   BROWSERSVCSTARTUPTYPE:         Disabled
>   CLTCTLRNAME:                   <empty>
>   CLTRESULTDIR:                  <empty>
>   CLTSTARTUPTYPE:                0
>   CLTSVCACCOUNT:                 <empty>
>   CLTSVCPASSWORD:                <empty>
>   CLTWORKINGDIR:                 <empty>
>   COMMFABRICENCRYPTION:          0
>   COMMFABRICNETWORKLEVEL:        0
>   COMMFABRICPORT:                0
>   CONFIGURATIONFILE:             C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\130\Setup Bootstrap\Log\20191126_195755\ConfigurationFile.ini
>   CTLRSTARTUPTYPE:               0
>   CTLRSVCACCOUNT:                <empty>
>   CTLRSVCPASSWORD:               <empty>
>   CTLRUSERS:                     <empty>
>   ENABLERANU:                    true
>   ENU:                           true
>   EXTSVCACCOUNT:                 <empty>
>   EXTSVCPASSWORD:                <empty>
>   FEATURES:                      SQLENGINE
>   FILESTREAMLEVEL:               0
>   FILESTREAMSHARENAME:           <empty>
>   FTSVCACCOUNT:                  <empty>
>   FTSVCPASSWORD:                 <empty>
>   HELP:                          false
>   IACCEPTROPENLICENSETERMS:      false
>   IACCEPTSQLSERVERLICENSETERMS:  true
>   INDICATEPROGRESS:              true
>   INSTALLSHAREDDIR:              C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\
>   INSTALLSHAREDWOWDIR:           C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\
>   INSTALLSQLDATADIR:             <empty>
>   INSTANCEDIR:                   C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server
>   INSTANCEID:                    SQLEXPRESS
>   INSTANCENAME:                  SQLEXPRESS
>   ISSVCACCOUNT:                  NT AUTHORITY\Network Service
>   ISSVCPASSWORD:                 <empty>
>   ISSVCSTARTUPTYPE:              Automatic
>   ISTELSVCACCT:                  <empty>
>   ISTELSVCPASSWORD:              <empty>
>   ISTELSVCSTARTUPTYPE:           0
>   MATRIXCMBRICKCOMMPORT:         0
>   MATRIXCMSERVERNAME:            <empty>
>   MATRIXNAME:                    <empty>
>   MRCACHEDIRECTORY:              
>   NPENABLED:                     0
>   PBDMSSVCACCOUNT:               <empty>
>   PBDMSSVCPASSWORD:              <empty>
>   PBDMSSVCSTARTUPTYPE:           0
>   PBENGSVCACCOUNT:               <empty>
>   PBENGSVCPASSWORD:              <empty>
>   PBENGSVCSTARTUPTYPE:           0
>   PBPORTRANGE:                   <empty>
>   PBSCALEOUT:                    false
>   PID:                           *****
>   QUIET:                         true
>   QUIETSIMPLE:                   false
>   ROLE:                          AllFeatures_WithDefaults
>   RSINSTALLMODE:                 DefaultNativeMode
>   RSSHPINSTALLMODE:              DefaultSharePointMode
>   RSSVCACCOUNT:                  <empty>
>   RSSVCPASSWORD:                 <empty>
>   RSSVCSTARTUPTYPE:              Automatic
>   SAPWD:                         <empty>
>   SECURITYMODE:                  <empty>
>   SQLBACKUPDIR:                  <empty>
>   SQLCOLLATION:                  SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
>   SQLSVCACCOUNT:                 NT Service\MSSQL$SQLEXPRESS
>   SQLSVCINSTANTFILEINIT:         true
>   SQLSVCPASSWORD:                <empty>
>   SQLSVCSTARTUPTYPE:             Automatic
>   SQLSYSADMINACCOUNTS:           DESKTOP-V440KD1\adida
>   SQLTELSVCACCT:                 NT Service\SQLTELEMETRY$SQLEXPRESS
>   SQLTELSVCPASSWORD:             <empty>
>   SQLTELSVCSTARTUPTYPE:          Automatic
>   SQLTEMPDBDIR:                  <empty>
>   SQLTEMPDBFILECOUNT:            1
>   SQLTEMPDBFILEGROWTH:           64
>   SQLTEMPDBFILESIZE:             8
>   SQLTEMPDBLOGDIR:               <empty>
>   SQLTEMPDBLOGFILEGROWTH:        64
>   SQLTEMPDBLOGFILESIZE:          8
>   SQLUSERDBDIR:                  <empty>
>   SQLUSERDBLOGDIR:               <empty>
>   SUPPRESSPRIVACYSTATEMENTNOTICE: false
>   TCPENABLED:                    0
>   UIMODE:                        AutoAdvance
>   UpdateEnabled:                 false
>   UpdateSource:                  Slipstream
>   USEMICROSOFTUPDATE:            false
>   X86:                           false
>   Configuration file:            C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\130\Setup Bootstrap\Log\20191126_195755\ConfigurationFile.ini
> Detailed results:
>   Feature:                       Database Engine Services
>   Status:                        Failed: see logs for details
>   Reason for failure:            An error occurred during the setup process of the feature.
>   Next Step:                     Use the following information to resolve the error, uninstall this feature, and then run the setup process again.
>   Component name:                SQL Server Database Engine Services Instance Features
>   Component error code:          0x84BB0001
>   Error description:             Attempted to perform an unauthorized operation.
>   Error help link:               http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink?LinkId=20476&ProdName=Microsoft+SQL+Server&EvtSrc=setup.rll&EvtID=50000&ProdVer=13.0.5026.0&EvtType=0x476BF04A%400xBB814387&EvtType=0x476BF04A%400xBB814387
>   Feature:                       SQL Browser
>   Status:                        Passed
>   Feature:                       SQL Writer
>   Status:                        Passed
>   Feature:                       SQL Client Connectivity
>   Status:                        Passed
>   Feature:                       SQL Client Connectivity SDK
>   Status:                        Passed
>   Feature:                       Setup Support Files
>   Status:                        Passed
> Rules with failures:
> Global rules:
> Scenario specific rules:
> Rules report file:               C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\130\Setup Bootstrap\Log\20191126_195755\SystemConfigurationCheck_Report.htm
> ```